# How can I serialize object containing objects in java?

Tags: java, serialization, save, load

In our term project, we are responsible for making the desktop version of a board game. My role is to implement save and load methods. For this reason, I am working on serialization. I am trying to serialize objects that contain other objects. To visualize, I prepared some example classes.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Player  implements Serializable
{
   static int id;
   static String name;

   public Player(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }   
}
```

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Team implements Serializable
{
   String name;
   transient Player c;
   int[] numbers;


   public Team(String name, String capt){
      this.name = name;
      this.c = new Player(capt);
   }

   public Player getC()
   {
      return c;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }
}
```

```
public class test implements Serializable
{  
   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException 
   {
      Team t1 = new Team("Juventus", "Ronaldo");  
      Team t2 = new Team("Barcelona", "Messi");
      File file = createSave("1");
      save(file,t1,t2);
      Team[] teams = load(file);
      System.out.println("Team 1 is: " + teams[0].getName());  
      System.out.println("Team 2 is: " + teams[1].getName());
      System.out.println("Captain of team 1 is: " + teams[0].getC().name);
      System.out.println("Captain of team 2 is: " + teams[1].getC().name);


   }  
   private static File createSave(String gameId) throws IOException   
   { 
      File file = new File(gameId + ".txt");
      if (file.createNewFile())
      {
         System.out.println("File is created!");
      } 
      else 
      {
         System.out.println("File already exists.");
      }
      return file;     
   }

   private static void save(File file, Team t1, Team t2)throws IOException   
   { 
      FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
      ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
      o.writeObject(t1);
      o.writeObject(t2);
      o.close();
      f.close();

   }

   private static Team[] load(File file)throws IOException   
   { 

      try {

      Team[] teams = new Team[2];
      FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
      ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
      Team team1 = (Team) oi.readObject();
      Team team2 = (Team) oi.readObject();
      teams[0] = team1;
      teams[1] = team2;
      oi.close();
      fi.close();
      return teams;



      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File not found");
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    return null;
   }

}
```

To summarize the code part: I create a player class and a team class that contains player objects. In team class, there is a method that returns the captain of the team. I create two team instance, first one is Juventus and the captain is Ronaldo. The second one is Barcelona and the captain is Messi. Then I stored these two team objects to a txt file by using ObjectOutputStream. And in the load method, I loaded the two teams by using ObjectInputStream and return them as an array.

When I tried to reach the name variables of two team object I could. However, I could not reach the captains of the teams. Only last created player object is available. Let me share my output:

File already exists.

Team 1 is: Juventus

Team 2 is: Barcelona

Captain of team 1 is: Messi

Captain of team 2 is: Messi

As seen in the output I can only reach lastly created inner object. The Player Ronaldo is lost now.
I would be very happy if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all you need practice and learn more about foundamentals of java.
The mistake what you did is in the class Player. You set name as a static field. All of you Players can have only 1 name.

Try replace you class like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Player implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Next in Team class just remove transient

```
Player c;
```

And in the main class use

```
System.out.println("Captain of team 1 is: " + teams[0].getC().getName());
System.out.println("Captain of team 2 is: " + teams[1].getC().getName());
```

Now your code should work :) It's not perfect but this should resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for serializing and deserializing objects. Take look at it :)